# Collaboration (CRC Card)

Tags: java, collaboration, crc

```
public class Testing //main app class
{    
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
            //create instances
            Customer c = new Customer(...);
            Supplier s = new Supplier(...);                
            Project p = new Project(123, "abc", "qwerty", "asas", c, s);
            Invoice i = new Invoice(789, p, "asas", true);                
            Calculation cost = new Calculation();
            cost.calculateCost(i,p);                
            Helper h = new Helper();
            h.printFile(i,p,cost);
            
    }
 
}
```

For the above class, it can be seen that project uses customer and supplier as its CONSTRUCTOR parameter. Next, the entire project object is thrown into invoice class as its CONSTRUCTOR parameter too, which creates a unique invoice.

Next, there is another 2 class, the Calculation.java and Helper.java which takes in (invoice, project)  & (invoice, project, calculation) respectively into its NORMAL method parameter.

In this case, am I right to say that the passing of data through constructor parameter or normal class parameter BOTH means that they collaborates with the class they are receiving?

That is:

### Helper

print| invoice

.      -      | project

.      -      | calculation

or is it the other way round?

which is.. project collaborates with Helper.java instead?

Lastly, does the above way of coding implies a low or high coupling in my program design?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are any hard-and-fast answers to these questions. I suppose for me the decision about whether an object collaborates with another object is to think whether the first object *uses* the second object rather than the second being a part of or being related to the first.

So an invoice *has* a number of line items - I wouldn't call them collaborators, rather parts. But something that uses another object to complete its work *is* using a collaborator.

I don't think CRC cards are terribly well explained. What might be quite useful would be to focus on the differences between value objects, entities and services - I think domain-driven design focuses a lot on this. Also, do a Google search on London School or Mockist TDD which is all about building *loosely-coupled* systems where objects delegate to other objects (their collaborators).

This stuff is subtle, but you're on the right track.